# Create nested dictionaries from similar value in a column and use value as key for dictionaries contain all rows with that value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

All,
I have dataframe of bounding boxes in an image with each box being in a separate row. What I want to do is combine all the rows for a specific image.

```
                 image  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax       label
0   bookstore_video0_40.jpg   763   899   806   940  pedestrian
3   bookstore_video0_40.jpg  1026   754  1075   797  pedestrian
4   bookstore_video0_40.jpg   868   770   927   822       biker
5   bookstore_video0_40.jpg   413  1010   433  1040  pedestrian
21  bookstore_video0_80.jpg   866   278   917   328  pedestrian
22  bookstore_video0_80.jpg   761   825   820   865       biker
```

What I am thinking is maybe make this into a single level nested dictionary, note I am open to any solution and I am not fixed to a dictionary, like this maybe.

```
{'bookstore_video0_40.jpg': {'xmin': 1066, 'ymin': 802, 'xmax': 1093, 'ymax': 829, 'label': 'pedestrian'}
```

But with all rows data with the image name as the key. My end goal is to then pass this to a function that will sequentially write each row's data into a file. 
That all being said I am lost on how to group the data into blocks. I did groupby(‘image’) but I could not figure out how to then turn that data into something like what I want. Does anyone have ideas? I am pretty sure this is easy and I have looked around but most of the responses I have seen were for much more complicated questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you know what are the right properties for ie. `bookstore_video0_40.jpg` as there are multiple instances of that image what would you select for `xmin`

Comment: if your end goal is to write all this data to a file why not just keep the table format and write it to a csv or xls file via [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) or one of the many other file writing methods pandas has? Is the grouping to cut down on the file size or something?

Comment: I have to write it to a VOC XML format where each row is a bounding box for the same image. This is sort of a standard approach in machine learning where an image may have 1 to N bounding boxes. Some applications will turn that data into a CSV that looks like the tabular data format you mentioned. Other various flavors of XML. With the XML though you need to write just the image name once then all the rows that make up that bounding box under different branches. When you are done you make a new file for the next image etc. Sorry about not being clear.

Comment: Have you looked at this [pascal-voc-writer](https://github.com/AndrewCarterUK/pascal-voc-writer)? I've never used it before but maybe you could do this with a double for loop. the first loop would be like `for img in df['image'].unique():` then do the `writer = Writer(path, width, height)` part then the inner loop would be `for bb in df[df['image']==img]:` and inside of that loop, you could call that `writer.addObject(bb['label'], bb['xmin'], bb['ymin'], bb['xmax'], bb['xmin'])`, finally the `writer.save('path/to/img.xml')` part at the end.

Comment: I've written a voc writer. I just need to be able to pass data in such away that I can loop over it. I have a different data set where I do something similar but the data is already in a easy to consume form. For my project I've spending a lot of time editing, cleaning, transforming etc data. Not fun for me 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do You need is use dict with **tuple/list** applied on your **groupby**:

```
images_dict = dict(tuple(df.groupby('image')))
```

Comment: Ohh this is very close. It includes the image name but I can deal with that. Thank you for the education Cristian.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
new_dict = df.set_index('image').stack().groupby('image').apply(list).to_dict()


print(new_dict)
{'bookstore_video0_40.jpg': [763,
  899,
  806,
  940,
  'pedestrian',
  1026,
  754,
  1075,
  797,
  'pedestrian',
  868,
  770,
  927,
  822,
  'biker',
  413,
  1010,
  433,
  1040,
  'pedestrian'],
 'bookstore_video0_80.jpg': [866,
  278,
  917,
  328,
  'pedestrian',
  761,
  825,
  820,
  865,
  'biker']}
```

Comment: That looks like it would work as well. I'll have to keep track of position since column labels are gone but this seems like another good solution. I am going to play with both. Thank you very much Matthew.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this as a comment and not an answer, but the [link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20image%20%3D%20'40.jpg%2040.jpg%2040.jpg%2040.jpg%2080.jpg%2080.jpg'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20xmin%20%3D%20%5B763,%201026,%20868,%20413,%20866,%20761%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20ymin%20%3D%20%5B899,%20754,%20770,%201010,%20278,%20825%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20xmax%20%3D%20%5B806,%201075,%20927,%20433,%20917,%20820%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20ymax%20%3D%20%5B940,%20797,%20822,%201040,%20328,%20865%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20'pedestrian%20pedestrian%20biker%20pedestrian%20pedestrian%20biker'.split%28%29,%0A%29%29%0A%0A%0Afor%20img%20in%20df%5B'image'%5D.unique%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20img_df%20%3D%20df%5Bdf%5B'image'%5D%3D%3Dimg%5D.drop%28columns%20%3D%20'image'%29.reset_index%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20boxes%20%3D%20range%28img_df.shape%5B0%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28img,%20'%5Cn',%20img_df%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Ideally%20your%20custom%20voc%20writer%20can%20be%20inited%20here%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20with%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer%20%3D%20VocWriter%28f'path/%7Bimg%5B%3A-4%5D%7D.xml'%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%22New%20custom%20VOC%20Writer%20instance%20inited%20here!%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20box%20in%20boxes%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmin%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'xmin'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ymin%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'ymin'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmax%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'xmax'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ymax%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'ymax'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'label'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28xmin,%20ymin,%20xmax,%20ymax%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Inside%20of%20this%20loop,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20you%20can%20add%20each%20box%20to%20your%20VocWriter%20object%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer.addObject%28label,%20xmin,%20ymin,%20xmax,%20ymax%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22New%20bbox%20object%20added%20to%20writer%20instance%20here!%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Once%20you%20exit%20that%20inner%20loop,%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20you%20can%20save%20your%20data%20to%20your%20.xml%20file%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20with%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer.save%28f'path/%7Bimg%5B%3A-4%5D%7D.xml'%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%22.xml%20file%20saved%20here!%22%29&cumulative=true&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) was too long:

> I've written a voc writer. I just need to be able to pass data in such away that I can loop over it. I have a different data set where I do something similar but the data is already in a easy to consume form. For my project I've spending a lot of time editing, cleaning, transforming etc data. Not fun for me  – Robi Sen

How does your voc writer work? Is it similar to [the one that I linked to](https://github.com/AndrewCarterUK/pascal-voc-writer) (i.e does is use OPP and has class methods for adding bbox data to the xml writer instance and then another method to save that instance to an xml file?) The idea I had in my last comment was not written out well, here is a better example of what I meant:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    image = '40.jpg 40.jpg 40.jpg 40.jpg 80.jpg 80.jpg'.split(),
    xmin = [763, 1026, 868, 413, 866, 761],
    ymin = [899, 754, 770, 1010, 278, 825],
    xmax = [806, 1075, 927, 433, 917, 820],
    ymax = [940, 797, 822, 1040, 328, 865],
    label = 'pedestrian pedestrian biker pedestrian pedestrian biker'.split(),
))


for img in df['image'].unique():
    img_df = df[df['image']==img].drop(columns = 'image').reset_index()
    boxes = range(img_df.shape[0])
    print(img, '\n', img_df)

    # Ideally your custom voc writer can be inited here
    # with something like:

    # v_writer = VocWriter(f'path/{img[:-4]}.xml')
    print('New custom VOC XML Writer instance inited here!')

    for box in boxes:
        xmin = img_df.loc[box,'xmin']
        ymin = img_df.loc[box,'ymin']
        xmax = img_df.loc[box,'xmax']
        ymax = img_df.loc[box,'ymax']
        label = img_df.loc[box,'label']
        print(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

        # Inside of this loop, 
        # you can add each box to your VocWriter object
        # something like:

        # v_writer.addObject(label, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
        print('New bbox object added to writer instance here!')

    # Once you exit that inner loop,
    # you can save your data to your .xml file
    # with something like:

    # v_writer.save(f'path/{img[:-4]}.xml')
    print(f'path/{img[:-4]}.xml file saved here!')
```

[step through the example in python tutor to get a better idea of my idea here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20image%20%3D%20'40.jpg%2040.jpg%2040.jpg%2040.jpg%2080.jpg%2080.jpg'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20xmin%20%3D%20%5B763,%201026,%20868,%20413,%20866,%20761%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20ymin%20%3D%20%5B899,%20754,%20770,%201010,%20278,%20825%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20xmax%20%3D%20%5B806,%201075,%20927,%20433,%20917,%20820%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20ymax%20%3D%20%5B940,%20797,%20822,%201040,%20328,%20865%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20'pedestrian%20pedestrian%20biker%20pedestrian%20pedestrian%20biker'.split%28%29,%0A%29%29%0A%0A%0Afor%20img%20in%20df%5B'image'%5D.unique%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20img_df%20%3D%20df%5Bdf%5B'image'%5D%3D%3Dimg%5D.drop%28columns%20%3D%20'image'%29.reset_index%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20boxes%20%3D%20range%28img_df.shape%5B0%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28img,%20'%5Cn',%20img_df%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Ideally%20your%20custom%20voc%20writer%20can%20be%20inited%20here%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20with%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer%20%3D%20VocWriter%28f'path/%7Bimg%5B%3A-4%5D%7D.xml'%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28'New%20custom%20VOC%20XML%20Writer%20instance%20inited%20here!'%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20box%20in%20boxes%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmin%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'xmin'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ymin%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'ymin'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmax%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'xmax'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ymax%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'ymax'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20img_df.loc%5Bbox,'label'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28xmin,%20ymin,%20xmax,%20ymax%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Inside%20of%20this%20loop,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20you%20can%20add%20each%20box%20to%20your%20VocWriter%20object%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer.addObject%28label,%20xmin,%20ymin,%20xmax,%20ymax%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28'New%20bbox%20object%20added%20to%20writer%20instance%20here!'%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Once%20you%20exit%20that%20inner%20loop,%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20you%20can%20save%20your%20data%20to%20your%20.xml%20file%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20with%20something%20like%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20v_writer.save%28f'path/%7Bimg%5B%3A-4%5D%7D.xml'%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28f'path/%7Bimg%5B%3A-4%5D%7D.xml%20file%20saved%20here!'%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and way more than I would expect. Give me a little or maybe till tomorrow and I'll post the whole working code if I can.  Really appreciate this as well as I have never seen this python tutor site. Thank you for informing me!

Answer (score 1):

@Phillyclause89 here is a working example based on your example with the exception of reading in the actual XML files. Thank you very much. I suspect your answer will be useful since this is something that people doing machine vision run into when doing things like cutting up 4K images that have already been annotated.

```
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    image = '40.jpg 40.jpg 40.jpg 40.jpg 80.jpg 80.jpg'.split(),
    xmin = [763, 1026, 868, 413, 866, 761],
    ymin = [899, 754, 770, 1010, 278, 825],
    xmax = [806, 1075, 927, 433, 917, 820],
    ymax = [940, 797, 822, 1040, 328, 865],
    label = 'pedestrian pedestrian biker pedestrian pedestrian biker'.split(),
))


for img in df['image'].unique():
    img_df = df[df['image']==img].drop(columns = 'image').reset_index()
    boxes = range(img_df.shape[0])
    print(img, '\n', img_df)

    # Ideally your custom voc writer can be inited here
    # with something like:
    image = img
    # v_writer = VocWriter(f'path/{img[:-4]}.xml')
    print("New custom VOC Writer instance inited here!")

    depth = 3
    filepath = PurePosixPath('image')
    annotation = ET.Element('annotation')
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'folder').text = str(image)
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'filename').text = str(image)
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'segmented').text = '0'
    size = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'size')
    ET.SubElement(size, 'width').text = str('0')
    ET.SubElement(size, 'height').text = str('0')
    ET.SubElement(size, 'depth').text = str('3')

    for box in boxes:
        xmin = img_df.loc[box,'xmin']
        ymin = img_df.loc[box,'ymin']
        xmax = img_df.loc[box,'xmax']
        ymax = img_df.loc[box,'ymax']
        label = img_df.loc[box,'label']
        print(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

        # Inside of this loop, 
        # you can add each box to your VocWriter object
        # something like:

        ob = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'object')
        ET.SubElement(ob, 'name').text = str(img_df.loc[box,'label'])
        ET.SubElement(ob, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
        ET.SubElement(ob, 'truncated').text = '0'
        ET.SubElement(ob, 'difficult').text = '0'
        bbox = ET.SubElement(ob, 'bndbox')
        ET.SubElement(bbox, 'xmin').text = str(img_df.loc[box,'xmin'])
        ET.SubElement(bbox, 'ymin').text = str(img_df.loc[box,'ymin'])
        ET.SubElement(bbox, 'xmax').text = str(img_df.loc[box,'xmax'])
        ET.SubElement(bbox, 'ymax').text = str(img_df.loc[box,'ymax'])

    # Once you exit that inner loop,
    # you can save your data to your .xml file
    # with something like:

    # v_writer.save(f'path/{img[:-4]}.xml')
    print(".xml file saved here!")

    fileName = str(img)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(annotation)
    tree.write("./mergedxml/" + fileName + ".xml", encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Looks great! My thoughts are 1) it looks like the filenames you'll be saving these `.xml` files to will include the original `.jpg` extension (i.e. `bookstore_video0_40.jpg`'s would be saved as `bookstore_video0_40.jpg.xml`) it's more of a cosmetic thing since only the last extension should be used by the OS to recognize the file type, but I thought it would look a little nicer if you removed the `.jpg` before saving the file.  2)  you call `str` function a lot, which may be unnecessary, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding the object types of the data in your `DataFrame` or how your writer works.